# HOW do i do a data append against multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I added a column into table A and right now it is empty. What i want to do is take the phone column from table `consumer` and input it into appphone of table `diabetic` as long as the first name, last name, address, city, state, and zip, match up in both tables. Below is the query i have been trying and in theory should work but is not. I keep getting the same error no matter which way i change the query.--

error 'subquery returns more than one row'

---

```
UPDATE Diabetic_DB
SET Diabetic_DB.AppPhone = (SELECT Consumer.PHONE FROM Consumer
WHERE Consumer.FN = Diabetic_DB.FirstName
and Consumer.LN = Diabetic_DB.LastName and Consumer.ADDR = Diabetic_DB.Address1
and Consumer.CITY = Diabetic_DB.City and Consumer.ST = Diabetic_DB.State
and Consumer.ZIP = Diabetic_DB.Zip)

WHERE EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT(PHONE) FROM Consumer WHERE Consumer.FN = Diabetic_DB.FirstName
and Consumer.LN = Diabetic_DB.LastName and Consumer.ADDR = Diabetic_DB.Address1
and Consumer.CITY = Diabetic_DB.City and Consumer.ST = Diabetic_DB.State
and Consumer.ZIP = Diabetic_DB.Zip)
```

---

the original query i ran looked like this.

```
UPDATE Diabetic_DB
SET Diabetic_DB.AppPhone = Consumer.PHONE
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Consumer WHERE Consumer.FN = Diabetic_DB.FirstName
and Consumer.LN = Diabetic_DB.LastName and Consumer.ADDR = Diabetic_DB.Address1
and Consumer.CITY = Diabetic_DB.City and Consumer.ST = Diabetic_DB.State
and Consumer.ZIP = Diabetic_DB.Zip)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
UPDATE Diabetic_DB
    INNER JOIN Consumer ON 
    Consumer.FN = Diabetic_DB.FirstName
    and Consumer.LN = Diabetic_DB.LastName and Consumer.ADDR = Diabetic_DB.Address1
    and Consumer.CITY = Diabetic_DB.City and Consumer.ST = Diabetic_DB.State
    and Consumer.ZIP = Diabetic_DB.Zip
SET Diabetic_DB.AppPhone = Consumer.PHONE
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM Diabetic_DB INNER JOIN Consumer_Experian_122013 ON
Consumer_Experian_12201' at line 3

Comment: I am sorry, i thought i said it in the beginning.--It is mysql